# BIP39 Checksum fails sometimes

Tags: cryptography, python-3.7, bitcoin, checksum, cryptocurrency

I have this snippet of code which will be used to implement a mnemonic phrase generator according to [BIP39 Spec](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).
The problem is that most of the times the checksum is not correct, but in some cases it works, it depends on the given entropy. (I've used [iancoleman.io bip39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) for testing my checksum).

The following cases were observed:

128-bits of entropy were used.

```
Correct
Entropy:  10111101100010110111100011101111111110100010000101111110100101100000001100111111001100010010010011110110011010010010001011011000
Checksum: 1110

Incorrect
Entropy:  01011010000000110011001001001001001110100011100101010001001100111001111111000110000000011011110111011000011001010111001101111100
My checksum: 1010
Iancoleman checksum:1110
```

The first was a successful case, but the second failed. Below you can find my functions.

What did I miss?

```
def fill_bits(binary, bits):
    if len(binary) < bits:
        return "0" * (bits - len(binary)) + binary
    return binary


# generate a given number of entropy bits
def generate_entropy(bits=256):
    if bits < 128 or bits > 256:
        raise EntropyRangeExceeded

    entropybits = bin(int.from_bytes(os.urandom(bits // 8), byteorder=sys.byteorder))[2:]
    return fill_bits(entropybits, bits)


# returns the sha256 hash of the given input
def sha256(_input):
    return hashlib.sha256(_input.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()


# returns the checksum of the input hash
# checksum is given by the first (entropy length / 32)
# bits of the sha256 hash applied on entropy bits
def get_checksum(_entropy):
    entropy_length = len(_entropy) // 32
    return bin(int(sha256(_entropy), 16))[2:][:entropy_length]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sha256` the hash is calculated wrongly. No Utf8 encoding may be performed. Instead, the entropy must be represented as a byte array (see `to_bytes`) and the hash must be generated from this:

```
import hashlib
def sha256(_entropy):
    entBytes = int(_entropy, 2).to_bytes(len(_entropy) // 8, byteorder='big')
    return hashlib.sha256(entBytes).hexdigest()
```

Furthermore, the hash must be padded with leading 0-values to a length of 256 bit (see `zfill`), so that the leading 0-values are also considered in the checksum:

```
def get_checksum(_entropy):
    entropy_length = len(_entropy) // 32
    return bin(int(sha256(_entropy), 16))[2:].zfill(256)[:entropy_length];
```

Example 1, from [here](https://coldbit.com/bip-39-basics-from-randomness-to-mnemonic-words/), step 4:

```
_entropy = '0011001010000101011111010000101111111111101000001001000001001010110100010101111001001011000100111100011110001001111011110111011010010100110011001110111001100010111011010010101101010011110100100110101111110001100101011001000110100010000110110001100101110001'
print(get_checksum(_entropy)) # 11110011
```

Example 2, your second example:

```
_entropy = '01011010000000110011001001001001001110100011100101010001001100111001111111000110000000011011110111011000011001010111001101111100'
print(get_checksum(_entropy)) # 1110
```

Example 3, leading 0-values, compare with the result from [here](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/):

```
_entropy = '10111101100011110111100011101111111110100010000101111110100101100000001100111111001100010010010011110110011011010010001011011000'
print(get_checksum(_entropy)) # 0010
```

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood how to properly hash the entropy in order to get the checksum. Thanks for helping.